# Verify Green's theorem for $ M = -y/(y^2 + x^2) $ , $ N = x/(y^2 + x^2) $

Tags: greens-theorem

Verify Green's theorem for $$ M = -y/(y^2 + x^2) $$      $$ N = x/(y^2 + x^2) $$

$$ R = \{ (x,y) / h^2 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \} $$ where  $ 0 \lt h \le 1 $

My attempt:

$ \int Mdx + Ndy = \int_0^{2\pi} \alpha d\alpha = 2\pi $

But while calculating RHS of stokes i.e. $ \iint\frac{dN}{dx} -\frac{dM}{dy} dxdy = 0 $ as integrand vanishes.

How to approach this RHS.

Comment: Have you tried anything? And I think you should double check your region R, because has you have it, it's empty.

Comment: Typo, here a disk is there without origin. So function is defined and green theorem  can be applied.

Comment: It's actually an annulus, and really, this isn't that hard a task. If you **really** need one, I will provide an answer, but only if you show anything you've done.

Comment: @Tars27: The problem isn't with the right-hand side, but the left: You haven't yet integrated over the entire boundary of $R$.

Comment: its coming $ 2  \pi $ only I have integrated over entire boundary.